# Prevent Outlook from sending winmail.dat (TNEF) with VBA or C#

Tags: c#, vba, email, outlook, winmail.dat

I am creating messages from MS Word mail merge instrument using Adobe PDFMaker Office COM Addin. I receive a list of messages with pdf-attachments in my Outbox in MS Outlook. But besides the necessary .pdf-attachment all the emails are being sent  with "trash" winmail.dat attachment, which confuses the recipients (who do not use Outlook) a lot.  
I want to get rid of these winmail.dat attachments in the letters with VBA (the best way), but possibly - with C# (if it's impossible using VBA).
I can set using VBA the format of my mails to plain text, but it doesn't help.

Edit: If one manually deletes winmail.dat, it will be attached again by Outlook during the sending process.

There is a great article [Forcing Plain Text With MAPI](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stephen_griffin/archive/2008/08/04/forcing-plain-text-with-mapi.aspx) about the mechanism of getting rid of winmail.dat (how does it work), but unfortunately author used C++, which I am not familiar with.  
So, as far as I understood, it is necessary to set 3 MAPI flags to avoid TNEF comletely:

- MAPI_SEND_NO_RICH_INFO
- ENCODING_PREFERENCE
- ENCODING_MIME

I was using OutlookSpy to investigate MAPI flags in my outgoing emails, but even have not found such flags.  
I have read also about [Redemption library](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/objects.htm) and its possibilities, but I have not found any hints about these MAPI flags either.  
Can anybody explain or just suggest: how to set this flags using VBA or C#?  
or probably in other way get rid of winmail.dat sending?

Comment: This describes a non-programming solution https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/958012

Answer (score 0):

Set the special named property UseTnef (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8582000B`) to false using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty`.